# Hotmail import contacts sample

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, hotmail

I need c#,and/or asp.net sample of imports user contacts from hotmail.

By different ways (oauth wrap or if you know else way please say to me)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Live Messenger Connect for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff749458.aspx

<strike>You can use the [Windows Live API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463974.aspx) to do this</strike>

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. Maybe any peoples already have working sample.

Comment: This topic describes Windows Live features that have been deprecated. Deprecated features should not be used in new applications. For information about the technology that replaces these features, see Windows Live Messenger Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provide Messenger Connect API sample,

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/messengerconnect

And, there is a sample **ASP.NET_Contacts_and_Profiles_Sample.zip** in this page,
[Messenger Connect Code Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=messengerconnect&DownloadId=12966)

Maybe, this can help you.